# WPF set TextWrapping.Wrap global for multiline TextBox

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox, asp.net-4.5, word-wrap

How can i set in WPF-Textboxes `TextWrapping = TextWrapping.Wrap` for all multiline textboxes (`AcceptsReturn = true`) in my application? Is their some thing possible with styles?

I found a way with reflection, but their must be more elegant ways.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a default Style for TextBox, with a Trigger on the AcceptsReturn property:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="TextBox">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="AcceptsReturn" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="TextWrapping" Value="Wrap"/>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</Application.Resources>
```

Comment: Thank you for your fast answer, you set the property always to Wrap, not only if it is an multiline textbox.

Comment: You mean if AcceptsReturn is true?

Comment: Ok, found a solution thats working prettiy nice. If you add this to your answer i will accept it: `<Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="AcceptsReturn" Value="True">`... Thank you

Comment: You should have included that in your question.